# Laravel / InertiaJS / VueJS / ViteJS / Octane / SSR - A Working Configuration?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, vite, inertiajs

I'm trying to get my website project up and running with `Laravel 10`, `InertiaJS 1`, `VueJS 3`, and `ViteJS 4`, using `Laravel Octane` and `Vue/Vite SSR`. For the life of me I cannot seem to get a configuration that works properly... I've tried everything I can think of to Google, and nothing seems to work 100%...Either:

1. the assets aren't published to the public folder, or
2. they are published properly but they're being linked to files that don't exist because the folder is nested twice (/public/build/public/build/), or
3. I get an error after build that says the built version of Vue doesn't provide an export named 'createApp', or
4. I get an error that says 'resources/js/app.css' could not be found in manifest.json (despite it being imported within app.js and not referenced directly in the build process), or
5. Any number of endless issues I cannot seem to avoid.

[All my relevant files are in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/cjholowatyj/a0bca07aaef09b4bc5d56c83280159d0)

Right now, the error I'm getting in console is `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/build/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=35631b10' does not provide an export named 'createApp' (at app.js:28:9)` Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the contents of the vue.js file returned from the build process:

[image: Bundled VueJS file returned from the build process]

Am I able to do something with `compile` to resolve this issue?

Does anyone have a working configuration for all the aforementioned tools working in concert together? Or would know what I'm doing wrong here? (If the provided files are not enough context, I'm happy to pay someone to look more deeply into my repo and provide counsel/solutions).